# Display different field from model based on ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this is trivial stuff, but I am banging my head a bit here. You guys are always much more helpful.

I have two models: Contact and Group. Group has_many contacts and Contact belongs_to group.

Therefore Contact has a group_id field.

In my "show" view for a Contact, I have: `<%= @contact.group_id %>`
This shows "1".  Let's say "Sales" = group_id 1.

Now, the Group model has the default id field, and a group field, which contains the word "Sales", associated with id 1.

All I want to do is on my "show" page, display "Sales" instead of 1.

I'd imagine I need to create a variable within my "show" action in the ContactsController. I am just not sure what to put there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create association between contact and sales

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end
```

And in your view

```
<%= @contact.group.name %>
```

You can also get all the contacts of a particular group like

```
group.contacts
```

Comment: Damn, I knew it was something real simple. Appreciate it!

Comment: How does this work on the index page? <%= contact.group.name %> doesn't seem to work. You typically don't use @ on the index page.

Comment: It depends on how your action is setup. There is nothing like "You typically don't use @ on the index page"

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= @contact.group.name %>
```

you can access related models from each other just like this:

```
<model>.<related_model>
```

and then go on to ask for any attributes from the related model